# CakePHP 4 How to pass error message from model to controller?

Tags: cakephp-4.x

trying to grasp CakePHP 4 after transitioning from previous versions. Once there was this usefull way of propagating errors from Model to controller, that really helped a lot while trying to have thick models and slim controllers.

In your Model (Table) you just did:

`$this->error = "something got wrong';`

...in your controller you retrieved it via:

`$this->Modelname->error`

...and voila, you could use it wherever.

However CakePHP 4 is flipping me off with

*You have not defined the error association on App\Model\Table\Modelname*

What am I missing? Is there some new equivalent of these calls? Tried to go through documentation on [www.cakephp.org](http://www.cakephp.org), indeed there is a part about error handling, but that is quite overkill for something that was once simple.

And all SO / other questions related to this are pretty old, not for Cake PHP 4.

Thank you!

**EDIT**

After trying the approach within the same Model+Controller using much simpler method, **it obviously still works the good old aforementioned way (which is great!)**. The script must be crashing somewhere inside my much more complex method and this is just a very weird manifestation of the crash.

BTW I know this is hard to find in CakePHP documentation, but I was leveraging it for a long time. So just for clarity, I'm talking about this:

Model:

```
class ModelTable extends Table {

    public function myMegaBusinessLogic(){
        // doing stuff
        // ... but OOPS something is wrong ...
        $this->error = "It broke down! :( ";
        return false;
    } 

}
```

Controller:

```
class ModelController extends AppController{

    public function myAction() {

        if (!$this->Model->myMegaBusinessLogic()){
            $this->Flash->error(__($this->Model->error));
        } else {
            $this->Flash-success(__("Nailed it!"));
        }
    
    return $this->redirect(['action' => 'index']);
}
```

Comment: You should probably elaborate on what exactly you're trying to achieve in your application, eg what problem are you trying to solve by such logic, and what exactly are your referring to in what old version?! Personally I can't remember anything like that, I only remember `cakeError()`, which would create an error handler that could kill the application and render an error. And then there was validation errors, which were set using `invalidate()`.

Comment: Are you talking about [validation errors](https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/orm/entities.html#validation-errors)?

Comment: @ndm and Greg, thanks for answer.  
Yes it is indeed possible :) Validation errors are used a bit differently IMHO. I just tried it on a different model and controller, it was working alright. I'm fiddling around it. The script must be crashing somewhere else and this is just a weird manifestation.

Comment: You haven't found this in the Cake documentation anywhere, because it's not a feature of Cake. You're just setting a property on an object, using standard PHP functionality. Note that as of PHP 8.2, this "dynamic property" behaviour is deprecated, and will be removed entirely at some point.

Comment: @GregSchmidt Good to know, thank you! Never thought 'dynamic properties' were part of PHP, always thought I was just using Cake's Table properties.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, solved, it was my fault ofc...

Somewhere along the long way in my model table I forgot to actually do

```
$this->error = "Insert the reason for your failure...";
```

on one particular place and returned `false` to controller without the `error` being set. So when the controller called `$this->Flash->error(__($this->Model->error));`, of course it was confused...

Comment: This seems like probably bad design. Better to throw an exception with the error message in it and catch that in an appropriate place? Also, you should be wrapping your actual string ('Insert...') in the `__` function, not the variable. This way, the command line tool that extracts pot files for you will be able to work well.

Comment: @GregSchmidt I do wrap it of course, this was just example I did very quickly... Yes, you are right, based on what you said about removing 'dynamic properties' from PHP one day, the best course of action will be to throw it in an exception. I'll rework it in a couple of days and post the recommended solution. Thanks again!